# sympy.count_roots: type mismatch when working with real polynomial

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomial-math

I am using sympy and trying to compute number of roots of a polynomial

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Poly
p = Poly(x**4+0.1,x)
```

At this point, p is polynomial with domain 'RR': `Poly(1.0*x**4 + 0.1, x, domain='RR')`

If I try to compute number of roots in the interval, I get:

```
p.count_roots(0,2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'RealElement' and 'PythonRational'
```

However, if I define

```
q = Poly(x**3-1, x)
ans: Poly(x**3 - 1, x, domain='ZZ')

q.count_roots(0,2)
ans: 1
```

Similarly, if I ask for number of roots of `p` on the whole domain, that works as well

```
p.count_roots()
ans: 1
```

What should I do to supply correct types to count_roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When possible, use exact (instead of floating point) numbers in your symbolic expressions (this principle is true for all symbolic math software, not only sympy).

In this case, the constant term `0.1` in the definition of `p` can be replaced by the (exact) ratio representation `1/10`. Sympy uses `Rational` to describe ratios of numbers (since, an input `1/10` is interpreted by python as a floating point division and automatically transformed to `0.1`).

The following code works.

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Poly, Rational
p = Poly( x**4 + Rational(1,10), x)
p.count_roots(0,2)
```

> `0`

See also `sympy.nsimplify` for transforming arbitrary floating point numbers such as, e.g., `12.21525`, to (approximately equal) rationals.